# The website does completely detect my other SE accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask (maybe SO meta should get developer's attention quicker?).

I created my account on French SE today. I signed in with Google, and my account got created instantly. Except, some details were missing:

- My username was not automatically set. I was user945 for a while and asked to change it manually.
- I did not get my 100 points bonus.
- *About me* and other fields of my profile are not imported.

**However**

- The 'accounts' field of my user page shows correctly all the other 17 acocunts I have on SE.

It is not the first time I create an account on the SE network, I usualy proceed in that exat manner (sign in -> click on Google icon -> Takes me to Google page where I'm prompted to accept -> voilà).

I wonder if it's a bug, as I don't really have the means to reproduce it, or if I missed some step by mistake. How can I get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently problems with association, and [it is being looked at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep). Thanks for reporting the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You're now good to go, the association bonus backfill took care of things here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick!